# Replaced image in Android project, but won't update in the app

Tags: android, image

I have an Android project, and I wanted to replace two of the images I use in it with updated ones. So, with Eclipse i just delete the old one and replace it with new one with same name. Then i refresh the project.When i see this in drawable folder it was replaced but when i run this project it was still showing old image in my app.
Please let me know the solution.This is very urgent.

Comment: Maybe you only changed it in per example 'drawable-hdpi' and it is still the old picture in xhdpi/mdpi/ldpi ..?

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you have replaced the image(s) in all `drawable-*` folders. If that is the case, doing `Project->Clean` (and selecting your project) in Eclipse after the refresh of the project files should do the trick. Also, before re-deploying on the device, uninstall the previous version of the app.